# Submit spark application from laptop

Tags: apache-spark

I want to submit spark python applications from my laptop. I have a standalone spark cluster, and the master is running at some visible IP (`MASTER_IP`). After downloading and unzipping Spark on my laptop, I got this to work

```
./bin/spark-submit  --master  spark://MASTER_IP:7077   ~/PATHTO/pi.py
```

From what I understand, it is defaulting to client mode (vs cluster mode).  According to Spark (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) -
"only YARN supports cluster mode for Python applications." Since I'm not using YARN, I must use client mode.

My question is - do I need to download all of Spark on my laptop? Or just a few libraries?

I want to allow the rest of my team to use my Spark cluster, but I want them to do the least amount of work as possible. They don't need to setup a cluster. They only need to submit jobs to it. Having them downloading all of Spark seems like overkill.

So, what exactly is the minimum that they need?

Comment: https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver or https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel ?

Answer (score 1):

The `spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6` package I have here is 304MB unpacked. More than half, 175MB is made up of `spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar`, the main Spark stuff. You can't get rid of this unless you want to compile your own package maybe. A large part of the rest is `spark-examples-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar`, 113MB. Removing this and zipping back up is harmless and saves you a lot already.

However, using some tools such that they don't have to work with the spark package directly, like `spark-jobserver` (never used but never heard somebody very positive about the current state) or `spark-kernel` (needs your own code still to interface with it, or when used with notebook (see below) limited compared to alternatives) as suggested by Reactormonk makes it even easier for them.

A popular thing to do in that sense is set up access to a notebook. As you're using Python, [IPython with a PySpark profile](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-use-ipython-notebook-with-apache-spark/) would be most straightforward to set up. Other alternatives are [Zeppelin](http://zeppelin-project.org/) and [spark-notebook](https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook) (my favourite) for using Scala.